# How to adding a class and element to a div using jquery

Tags: jquery

I would like to add the following classes and element to a div on document ready.
So basically I want to add the glyphicon-time and a data-livestamp element to a div namely #inbs2. Any idea's?

```
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-time" aria-hidden="true"</span>
&nbsp<time data-livestamp="1447372205"></time>
```

I tried doing the following,

```
var time = data-livestamp="1447373405";
$(documnet).ready(){
    $('inbs2').add("p")
    .css('glyphicon glyphicon-time', 'true')
    .add('time');
};
```

But it didn't work... Please help

Comment: Just making sure, you want to add those `<span>` and `<time>` elements to a `<div id="inbs2">`?

Answer (score 0):

you need to use

**addClass()**  to add class to element

**attr('Attribute_Name')** to get element attribute

for data attr you can use **.data()**

to set attribute to element use **attr('Attribute_Name' , 'Value_you_want')**

```
$('#inbs2').addClass('glyphicon').addClass('glyphicon-time');
```

your code should be somethimg like this

```
var time = $('time').attr('data-livestamp');  //or you can use $('time').data('livestamp');
$(documnet).ready(){
    $('#inbs2').addClass('glyphicon-time').text(time); // there are more things instead of text() but thats rely of what you need to do .html()  ,  .append()
};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
  $('#inbs2').addClass("glyphicon-time");
  $('#inbs2').find('time').attr("data-livestamp",1447373405);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm interpreting that you want to generate `<span>` and `<time>` elements with the specified attributes, and then add them to an existing `<div id="inbs2">`.

I'm using [`addClass()`](https://api.jquery.com/addclass/), [`attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) and [`appendTo()`](http://api.jquery.com/appendto/).

```js
var time = livestamp = "1447373405";

$(function() {

  $container = $('#inbs2');

  $('<span>').addClass('glyphicon glyphicon-time')
             .attr('aria-hidden', true)
             .appendTo($container);
  
  $('<time>').attr('data-livestamp', livestamp)
             .appendTo($container);
  
});
```

```css
.glyphicon,
time {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 1em;
  height: 1em;
}
.glyphicon {
  background-color: tomato;
}
time {
  background-color: teal;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="inbs2"></div>
```